# ruby: Sending keystrokes to PTY in raw mode

Tags: ruby, pty

I'm attempting to add some more automated tests to the `ruby-newt` module. The code I have seems to work, but still requires manually hitting `ENTER` at the terminal in order for it to complete.

For example in the following code, `\t` will switch to the next button and `\r` will press the button, and both commands execute successfully, but the `ENTER` key still needs to be manually pressed at the terminal otherwise the program just hangs indefinitely.

If the line `wr.write "\t\r"` is commented out, then the program will time out and exit successfully after 10 seconds. I've tried `wr.flush`, but that does not help. I've also tried including `\n` in the command.

Is there anything additional I should include in the `write` command to ensure the child program successfully receives it?

```rb
require 'newt'
require 'pty'

def newt_run
  begin
    Newt::Screen.new
    Newt::Screen.centered_window(20, 15, 'Button')

    b1 = Newt::Button.new(1, 1, 'Button1')
    b2 = Newt::Button.new(1, 6, 'Button2')

    b = Newt::Button.new(1, 11, 'Exit')

    f = Newt::Form.new
    f.set_timer(10000)
    f.add(b1, b2, b) 

    rv = f.run
  ensure
    Newt::Screen.finish
  end
end

master, slave = PTY.open
rd, wr = IO.pipe

if fork.nil? then
  master.close
  wr.close

  $stdin.reopen(rd)
  $stdout.reopen(slave)
  $stderr.reopen(slave)

  newt_run
else
  slave.close
  rd.close

  wr.write "\t\r"
  Process.wait
end
```

Comment: Note: Inside a `def` you can just `ensure` without need for an explicit `begin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the newt C-library opens `/dev/tty` by default for input. It does not use stdin. This is why nothing you send it seems to work. It's not reading your pipe, it is reading `/dev/tty`.

Here is the problem in more detail:

1. Ruby newt calls `newtInit()` in the C-lib
2. `newtInit()` calls `SLang_init_tty`
3. `SLang_init_tty` attaches input to `/dev/tty` by default always.

If you [read the documentation](https://www.jedsoft.org/slang/doc/html/cref-10.html) of `SLang_init_tty` you will find that the variable `SLang_TT_Read_FD` determines if `/dev/tty` is used or not.

**Solution 1**:

You need to set `SLang_TT_Read_FD` to `stdin`, before calling `newtInit()` from Ruby.

**Solution 2:**

Use `setsid` and `ioctl(TIOCSCTTY)` to reassign the controlling terminal in the forked process (see [docs for ioctl here](https://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl)).

Working example:

```
TIOCSCTTY = 0x540E
master, slave = PTY.open

if fork.nil? then
  # Child process
  # Make group leader. Required for aquiring controlling TTY.
  Process.setsid

  master.close               # Close master side    
  STDIN.reopen(slave)        # Reassign STDIN
  STDIN.ioctl(TIOCSCTTY, 0)  # Reassign controlling TTY (important part)

  # Ensure master is ready
  slave.gets

  # Now we can run the UI
  newt_run
else
  # Parent process
  slave.close

  # Sync up with slave
  master.puts 'hello'

  # Allow for UI setup
  sleep 1

  master.write "\e[B" # Arrow down
  master.write "\e[B" # Arrow down
  master.write "\t"   # Tab
  master.write "\r"   # Enter

  Process.wait 
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe Solution 2 will work for my situation.